# Somando varios inputs com mesmo id jquery ou javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
então galera tenho seguinte codico
```

```
 function calcularFinal() {      
   var contas = document.querySelectorAll("#produ"); 
   var total = 0 ;
  for(var i= 0; i<contas.length; i++){
    var conta = parseFloat(contas[i].value.replace(',','.'));
   var valor = (conta+valor);
  }
  console.log(valor); 
}
```

elea pega varios inputs com mesmo ids neles nada mais tem do que um valor em float so queria somar todos eles mais n estou conseguindo ate pesei q era por causa da virgula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Criei um jsfiddle para exemplificar, mas abaixo segue uma função que faz isso.

```js
function calcularFinal(){
  soma = 0;
    numeros = document.querySelectorAll('#produ')
    .forEach((elemento) => {
        soma += Number.parseFloat(elemento.value);
    });
  console.log(soma);
}
```

Uma coisa importante é não ter vários elementos com o mesmo ID, o id deve ser único para cada elemento. Para isso, use classes.
No exemplo abaixo você pode ver isso.

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/jp10tmdo/)

Comment: vlw amigo pela dica acho q era isso mesmo q vc disse id deve ser unico obg pela dicas S2 funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar.